# How can I access a page that is not on the root and has inclusions

Tags: php, apache

I am working on a web application that uses PHP and JavaScript and I have some troubles accessing some pages that are not on the root if they are including other files (ie. 'include once').

```
[file system]/www/project/test/test.php
```

The project folder has the `index.php`. Here is an example of my code:

```
include_once('../config/config.php');
include_once('../database/database.php');
echo 'Test.php';

$config = new Config();
$dbhandle = new Database();

[...]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The error log from Apache tells me that there is no file config.php and database.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to relocate the path to the root path of your server like this :

```
 $root_path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ; //Returns the root path of your server

 //Then call your inlude_once with the absolute path
 include_once($root_path . '/project/config/config.php')
```

So now all your path are Absolute and not relative.
Hope that helps.

PS : You can also get confortable using a php framework that will do the magic of routing your dependencies easier on a bigger project.

Answer (score 1):

to get document root use

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

and hence

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project/config/config.php');
```

should work for you.